# Java while loop and other

Tags: java, loops, logic

I need help I am new to Java programming and I don't know how to fix my code.

I am trying to make a 007 game. I have created the `if` statements and it isn't looping around. If I add a `!` in front of the each statement in the `do`-`while` loop it causes a infinity loop.

How can I fix my programming.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DoubleOSeven {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Let's Play a game of 007 ");
    System.out.println("You can SHOOT, BLOCK, AND RELOAD");
    System.out.println("Both you and I start with one bullet");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Let's Start, Enter (shoot, reload , or block) ");
    String INput = input.nextLine();

    //User and Computer ammo
    int Userammo = 1;
    int ammo = 1;

    //Creates a random number between 1 and 3
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  output = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;


    do{
    //User chooses shoot
    if(INput.equals("shoot")){
        Userammo --;
        System.out.println("You took a shot, Your ammo count is at: " + Userammo);

    //User chooses reload
    }else if (INput.equals("reload")){
        Userammo ++;
        System.out.println("You reloaded, Your ammo count is at: " + Userammo);

    //User chooses block    
    }else if(INput.equals("block")){
        System.out.println("You blocked, Your ammo count is at: " + Userammo);  

    //If random is 1 shoot
    }if(output == 1){
        ammo ++;
        System.out.println("I took a shot at you, My ammo count is at: " + ammo);

    //If random is 2 block
    }else if(output == 2){
        System.out.println("I blocked, My ammo count is at: " + ammo);

    //If random is 3 reload 
    }else if(output == 3){
        ammo ++;
        System.out.println("I reloaded, My ammo count is at: " + ammo);

    //If both User and Computer shoot
    }if(output ==  1 && INput == "shoot"){
        System.out.println("It's a tie you we both die");

    }
    }while((output == 3 && INput == "shoot") && (output == 1 && INput == "reload") && (output ==  1 && INput == "shoot"));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: In order for the loop to work well, the question to the user and the computer random decision have to be inside the loop. In this way each loop has a new set of values for the variables.

```
// Declare variables 
String INput = "";
Random rand = new Random();
int output = 0;

do{
    // Ask user
    System.out.println("Enter (shoot, reload , or block) ");
    INput = input.nextLine();

    // Computer decision
    output = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;

    ...
```

Second: You need to have an explicit decision when to terminate the loop (ie the game). This can be done with one of the following

- the user wants to end the game (that needs one more option `quit` in the user choices)
- the computer wants to end the game (that needs a forth random number that means `quit`).
- some condition from the combination of user/computer ammo and user/computer shoot. That is you can end the game if some player is shot and has zero ammo.

In all these cases you need to

- declare a variable for the end of the game before the loop
- decide what to do in the loop
- continue the loop if not end of game

This is snippet for this:

```
boolean endOfGame = false;
...
do {
    ...
    if (  INput.equals("quit") 
       || (INput.equals("shoot") && ammo == 0)
       || (Userammo == 0 && output == 1) ) {
         endOfGame = true;
    } 
    ...
} while (!endOfGame);
```

You could have the same efect if you put the decision in the `while`, 
but in this way the decision for the end of game is more clear.
It is also possible to set the `endOfGame` to `true` in many different places in the loop.

**Edit: Some notes on coding style etc**

- It is a common good practice the names of the variables to start with low case letters (eg instead of `Userammo` use `userAmmo`). Names starting with capital letters denote classes.
- It makes the code easier to read if the names have some meaning. For example I would suggest the following changes for some of your variables

  - INput → userAction
  - Userammo → userAmmo
  - output → compAction
  - ammo → compAmmo
- Use final constants to give meaning to numbers or strings that appear in your code repeatedly.
- Start the `if` statement on a new line. (else if on the same line is ok)

Using these you could have written (and some comments are not needed)

```
public class DoubleOSeven {
    public static final String S_SHOOT = "shoot";
    public static final String S_BLOCK = "block";
    public static final String S_RELOAD = "reload";
    public static final int I_SHOOT = 1;
    public static final int I_BLOCK = 2;
    public static final int I_RELOAD = 3;

    ...
    System.out.println("Enter ("+ S_SHOOT + ", " + S_RELOAD + " or " + S_BLOCK + ") ");

    ...
    } else if(userAction.equals(S_BLOCK)){
        System.out.println("You blocked, Your ammo count is at: " + userAmmo);  
    }

    if(compAction == I_SHOOT){
        compAmmo--;    // I changed ++ to -- in order to be a fair game
        System.out.println("I took a shot at you, My ammo count is at: " + compAmmo);
    } else if(compAction == I_BLOCK){
        System.out.println("I blocked, My ammo count is at: " + compAmmo);
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while((output == 3 && INput == "shoot") && (output == 1 && INput == "reload") && (output ==  1 && INput == "shoot"));
```

should be

```
while((output == 3 && INput.equals("shoot")) || (output == 1 && INput.equals("reload")) || (output ==  1 && INput.equals("shoot")));
```

Comment: i changed my code but, how do i make it go continues until someone loses

Answer (score 0):

As per your condition as below

```
while((output == 3 && INput == "shoot") && (output == 1 && INput == "reload") && (output ==  1 && INput == "shoot"));
```

the loop will be executed only if the 3 conditions are true.

You need to make some changes in your condition

Answer (score 0):

All your && cases that are evaluated for this loop result in a false.

Let's say, T for all true cases and F for all F cases

```
If T&&T&&T then yes we = T (the case for adding !)
If T&&F&&F then F
IF F&&T&&F then F
...
IF F&&F&&F then F
```

So you need to re-evaluate what condition you want to cause to loop.

Are we looking for

```
(output==3 && Input=="shoot") || (output==1 && input=="reload") || (output==1 && input=="shoot")
```

to cause the next iteration?

This would make the case, where any of them are T, we get T.  If all of them are F, then we get F.